# R - Drawing multiple boxplots of different variables with the same scale / index in the same plot

Tags: r, plot, boxplot

Lets say I have 2 Variables with 20 data points each (0,1,2 or 3) and I want to plot boxplots of each of the variables but so that they share the y-axis in a diagram. How do I do this easily?

Writing `boxplot(var1,var2,data = mydata)` didn't work...

Answer (score 0):

You should provide reproducible data and you should tell us what error message(s) you received with your code. When a function does not perform as expected, it is good to read the manual page (`?boxplot`). Here are some made-up data similar to yours:

```
set.seed(42)
mydata <- data.frame(var1=sample(0:3, 20, replace=TRUE), var2=sample(0:3, 20, replace=TRUE))
```

Then the box plot is just

```
boxplot(mydata)  # Or boxplot(mydata[, c("var1", "var2")]) if you are excluding other columns
```

[image: Boxplot]